# QIcon in QMenu does not change image with mouse hover or click

Tags: qt, qmenu, qicon

I am trying to setup a QIcon for a QMenu that reflects normal, pressed, and disabled states but the image doesn't seem to change when I mouse hover/click over the icon. I have added 3 icons to my resources.qrc file reflecting normal, active, and disabled states.

Here are the macro definitions:

```
#define IMG_SETTINGS_NORMAL     ":/Images/icon-menu.png"
#define IMG_SETTINGS_ACTIVE     ":/Images/icon-menu-pressed.png"
#define IMG_SETTINGS_DISABLED   ":/Images/icon-menu-disabled.png"
```

Here is my code:

```
    m_pMenu->addAction(m_pAction1);
    m_pMenu->addAction(m_pAction2);

    QIcon settingsIcon;
    settingsIcon.addFile(IMG_SETTINGS_NORMAL,   QSize(), QIcon::Normal);
    settingsIcon.addFile(IMG_SETTINGS_ACTIVE,   QSize(), QIcon::Active);
    settingsIcon.addFile(IMG_SETTINGS_DISABLED, QSize(), QIcon::Disabled);
    m_pMenu->setIcon(settingsIcon);

    m_pMenuBar->setStyleSheet(
        R"style(
          QMenuBar::item:pressed
          {
              background: transparent;
          }
        )style");

    m_pMenuBar->addMenu(m_pMenu);
    m_pMenu->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
    m_pMenuBar->setNativeMenuBar(false);
```

Please let me know any other information I can provide. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Which OS do you run your code on? Do applications on your OS usually behave like this? Qt apps usually try to behave as it is the convention on the hosting OS!

Comment: I’m running on Ubuntu 14.04. I just want to know why only the Normal state icon is showing